# How to select text in the label control in DevExpress?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

Can I select text in the label control in DevExpress?

[image]

I need something like this:

[image]

**Edit**

[image]

```
private void AddLayoutItem(LayoutControlGroup group, string name, string description)
        {
            group.AllowHtmlStringInCaption = true;

            LabelControl label = new LabelControl
            {
                Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                Text = description,
                Font = new Font("Tahoma", 11),
                Padding = new Padding(25, 0, 0, 0),
                AutoSizeMode = LabelAutoSizeMode.Vertical,

                AllowDrop = true,
                BorderStyle = 0,
                IsAccessible = true
            };
            AddLayoutItem(group, name, label);
        }
```

Comment: Which component are you using for displaying text?

Comment: @MarkoJuvančič It is a  layout control, added a screenshot

Comment: I mean the components for displaying text. Which type is for example the component that says "IT Direktor"?

Comment: @MarkoJuvančič It is LabelControl. I tried to add AllowDrop, BorderStyle and IsAccessible but it son't work. Added code

Comment: This is why you can't select text. Use `TextEdit` and set it's `BorderStyle` property to `NoBorder` and `ReadOnly` to `true`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LabelControl` does not support selection of the displayed text.
However, this can be achived through `TextEdit`, which you can make look like a label, but users are able to select the text. Set it's BorderStyle property to NoBorder and ReadOnly to true.

Your code would look something like this:

```
private void AddLayoutItem(LayoutControlGroup group, string name, string description)
{
        group.AllowHtmlStringInCaption = true;

        var edit = new TextEdit
        {
            Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            Text = description,
            Font = new Font("Tahoma", 11)
        };
        edit.Properties.BorderStyle = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.BorderStyles.NoBorder;
        edit.Properties.ReadOnly = true;
        
        AddLayoutItem(group, name, edit);
 }
```